# MySQL Privileges, allowing/disallowing

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

I have been playing around with user privileges in MySQL database and I still can not get desired result.

Yesterday, I granted permissions, then revoked and the user did still have it. (same browser, only logged out). After restarting browser, it did work as expected.

Today, I set privileges

```
GRANT CREATE ON `testdb`.`testtbl` TO 'ttt'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test'
```

I didn't see only "testdb", but I saw table "test" too - and I shouldn't. When I went to database "testdb", I couldn`t create table. It said

> CREATE command denied to user 'ttt'@'localhost' for table 'ttbl'

SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE `ttbl` (
  `test1` int NOT NULL,
  `test2` int NOT NULL
) COMMENT='';
```

I think I am missing some point of this privileges, but I can't still figure out what's wrong.

What can be wrong when using only this commands? (not CREATE USER, not sure if it is mandatory)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, after changing privileges, **always** run the following command:

```
flush privileges;
```

It forces the MySQL runtime to actively reload the privileges table, as such flushing out all other outdated privileges. It does not do this automatically since it would have to detect changes to the authorization table proactively.

Comment: I tried it with flush privileges, but I am keep getting the error. Now I found another error (I am using adminer), it says "Access denied for user 'ttt'@'localhost' to database 'testdb'"

Comment: Without knowing all too much about your structure, I think you want to assign your `create` rights on the database, not the table as you are doing now.

Comment: I want to assign `create` rights for table only, not database

Comment: I'm really missing what you're trying to do then. What would `create` rights mean on a table? Rights to create that specific table which already exists? As stated in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges it's not a permissible privilege at the table level...

Comment: I am trying to allow user to create tables under specified database.

Comment: And as said, that means you should grant the `create` right on the place where the user will be creating the tables... on the database. You are now granting on ``testdb`.`testtbl``, which is already a table inside the database.